# Heatmap correlation with categorical variables

Tags: r, correlation

I've got a data table with Premium - the continuous dependent variable to be predicted and other independent variables such as Age, Height (continuous); Diabetes, Transplant (0: No, 1:Yes). I want to create a lower triangle heatmap to see the correlation between all the variables. I did search for the correlation including categorical variables and am aware that some methods could be used for such correlation are Cramer's V or Intraclass Correlation but don't know how to apply these to a lower triangle heatmap. Is it still fine to calculate correlation heatmap using integers to code categorical independent variables or I still need to use other correlation types? In case of the latter then how to do so? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to learn from your heatmap? Correlation involving categorical variables is a bit funky.

Comment: I want to know if there is any independent variables, regardless of categorical or continuous, are correlated to each other and also which independent variables are correlated to the dependent variables. If heatmap is not a good way then what should I do instead?